# Can we sell self hosted web application on google app marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

i have a web app that I host myself. I want to increase my market. Is it possible to sell my web app without hosting on google app engine on google app marketplace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when configuring your project with the Marketplace SDK, you need to specify the url of your application. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/building) you can find information on the services and authentication of users with Google.
Hope this helps.